# How to randomly iterate through an array once, and then repeatedly iterate in that order

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, shuffle

This is my array: `arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` I want to randomly iterate through it the first time and then iterate through it in the same (random) order each time after that. How would I do it? The only way I can think of would be to shuffle the arr, using something like [this shuffle function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) and then iterate through sequentially. For example:

```
newArr = shuffle(arr);
for(j = 0; j <5; j++) {
    for(i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++)
}
```

I am wondering if there is an easier, inline way, so that if items get appended to the array I do not have to reshuffle (and make a new `array` each time)

Comment: but the sequence would change either way when you change the array so shuffling seems like a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a second array. Next, populate the array with random numbers (ranging from 0 to `array.length`). Now create a for loop iterating through the secondary array. Each number in the array corresponds to an index in `array`.

Result: you can now iterate randomly through `array` without modifying the order of `array`.

Later on you can use the `splice()` function to add to the second array at random points (and `push()` to add to the main `array`).

Comment: This was the idea I figured, however, if I fill a second array with random numbers, there is the chance that a number could be duplicated, and a number could be left out (for instance the number 2 could randomly be generated twice)...right?

Comment: @Startec you would need to add a second for loop inside the random generator while loop which checks to see if there are any duplicate numbers generated. I've done some random number generation like this before for a Java random map generator. If you'd like, I could expand on this answer with some pseudo code.

Comment: Not necessary, it seems like the best way would be to shuffle the array and then sequentially loop.

Comment: @Startec oh yeah shuffle would work better I guess. I was thinking about it the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there no built-in function for that.
So... make a list of ints the same size as the array, and assign them 0..count-1. Then choose a number at random from 0 to the size of the list(-1) and REMOVE the number at that location and ADD it to a new (second) list.  Repeat until you the first list is empty.  The second list will be a random set of offset into the original range.